# Rendering hundreds of thousands of circles with react-konva

Tags: canvas, bigdata, visualization, react-konva

I'm working with react-konva to render big genetic datasets and I'm fairly new to both konva and react-konva. It has been extremely helpful for code iteration with its easy to use api. However, I'm running into scaling issues rendering tens/hundreds of thousands of `<circle /> or`` components. Currently, I'm just mapping over the dataset and returning a circle or rect since the code is very easy to read/write. Does konva do a draw() on each shape or does it already batch the draw calls? Is there a better way, or is it advised for me to switch to using vanilla canvas or look into a gl canvas option?

pseudo/abbreviated code illustrating what I'm currently doing below:

The code example shows what I've tried. I've used `<FastLayer />` to try to make it a bit more light weight.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Stage, FastLayer, Circle } from 'react-konva'; 

const RADIUS = 2;

const getLargeDataset = (width, height) => Array.from({ length: 100000 }).map((_, i) => ({
    x: Math.random() * width,
    y: Math.random() * height
}));

function CirclePlot({ width, height }) {
    const largeDataset = getLargeDataset(width, height);

    return (
        <Stage
            height={height}
            width={width}
        >
            <FastLayer>
                {largeDataset.map(({ x, y }, i) => (
                    <Circle
                        key={`circle:${i}`}
                        x={x}
                        y={y}
                        radius={RADIUS}
                    />
                ))}
            </FastLayer>
        </Stage>
    );
}
```

Result is slow to load and when I examine the memory in chrome dev-tools I see each Circle being held separately.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to just show circles on the page, then `react`, `konva` and `react-konva` are the huge overhead. It will consume a lot of memory for thousands of shapes.

It will be better to use a canvas API directly (2d or webgl).

Or may think about some ways to simplify the drawing. For example do not render circles, if they are not visible on the screen.